# ClassCastException with Google sample code: how should my my_text_view.xml file look?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to learn how to use `RecyclerView`, but I keep running into an error with the `onCreateViewHolder` method. I suspect that my `my_text_view.xml` is not formatted properly. Google's documentation does not provide an example XML file for me to use.

Here is the adapter class (taken straight from Google's tutorial), as well as the XML file beneath it:

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false); //this line throws a ClassCastException
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.textView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

And the content of `my_text_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML file's root view is `LinearLayout` but the code is inflating it and then trying to cast it to a TextView.

You can either remove the LinearLayout from xml so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

**OR, ALTERNATIVELY**

You can remove the type cast in `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
 View v =  (LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false)); 
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
```

And in your ViewHolder:

```
   textView = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

> I would recommend that you go with second option if you are planning
>   to modify this later on as you can't add more items to viewholder if
>   you go with first solution. Otherwise it would crash again.

Answer (score 1):

Your root layout in xml is `linearLayout` you should use `findViewById()` to find `TextView` child in viewHolder class:

try this:

```
 public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textView;
    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @mperic, I would absolutely go this route as you will create RecyclerViews that have multiple UI pieces and even multiple ViewHolders, so you should get used to this concept.